# How to combine/merge attribute data from 1 layer to another, polygon to point, merge attributes and wrap/carriage return attributes

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, merge, attribute-joins, select-by-location

I am trying to merge field areas from a polygon layer into a point layer
So the field area from this polygon onto the dot layer.

[image]

Where the Point layer, has an String attribute, and set to Multiline, so it would look like this:

[image]

I can generated the area measurement, using Field Calculator QGIS 2.14, Expression $area
(Though I understand there can be/is errors with this method)

Point Layer:

[image]

Polygon layer:

[image]

[image]

#### Join by field location

You can do a spatial join but that just adds another column with the attributes, but I need another step.

Join by field location I believe adds the area location from the polygon layer to the point layer.  Go to Menu, Vector, Data Management Tools, Join Attributes by location
(Hopefully this will work when you have smaller polygons and points closer together as the distances between points/polygons is quite small)

[image]

**I need to merge the columns generated as well.  So the area column needs to become more like the Label column. (see picture)**

I am looking to avoid manually copying and pasting the data from one column into another in the attribute table.  In that case, it will be easier to measure each polygon individually using the identify tool, and then enter the label name and area one by one.

[image]

#### Try 3 - Pnz answer - Unsuccessful

Create 2 new layers
Names 2 - Point layer
Attribute: Label, String, multiline

Polygon 2 - polygon layer

Created area attribute on Polygon 2 using field calculator

Had both layers editable

Ran Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join by Location
[image]

Created a new point layer but with 3 attribute columns:
Label, id, area
[image]

#### Test 2

Ran Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Intersect
[image]

This creates a new point layer with 3 attribute columns
Label, id, area
[image]

**The issue is that the label needs to be as follows**

[image]

I don't think "intersect" or "join by location" will join, and "wrap" in effect 2 lots of attribute column data.

I have had both layers editable, but since the Intersect and Join by location tool create **new** layers, I don't think the layers being editable is the issue.

Comment: I think you need to use MMQGIS to export and import csv files.
I think you can wrap the attributes using excel and probably excel macros.
I will do some research and post an answer if I get one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help managed to sort the issue.
You can merge columns using the field calculator and add /n to add a new line

Rough notes

Point layer - labels you want:

Name
area ha

Polygon layer: polygons + areas

1. Set Project Projection to local map area, i.e. base units needs to be in metres ect.. so that the area calculation is more accurate.

#### 2. Polygon layer, create the areas

Turn toggl editing on
Open attribute table
Select Field calculator
Create new field, give name: Area
Output Field type: Decimal number (real)
Output Field Length: 2, Precision 2
**I think if you set the precision to 2 it will correctly round the area to the length of the precision**
Expression: $area

**There are errors this way of producing areas**

You get the following in the attribute table

id ¦ area¦
0  ¦ 1.19 ¦
1  ¦ 3.74 ¦
2  ¦ 4.52 ¦
3  ¦ 2.81 ¦
ect...

Save the layer

2.b  You can add the labels to the polygon layer which can be quicker if you have many to add.

### 3. Point layer

You need a point in the middle of each polygon.  Take care with very small/close together polygons.

You can add the labels as you add the points or you can use Join by location function to add labels and areas from the polygon layer.

Run Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join by Location
Input vector layer: Points layer
Intersect layer: Polygon layer

Output, press browse, go to where you want to save the shp file, give a file name like: Labels
Tick
Add result to canvas
Press OK

4. Open the attribute table on the new layer: Labels, and enable toggle editing

Attribute table be like this:

id ¦ Name    ¦ id ¦ area ¦
5  ¦ Label 1 ¦ 0  ¦ 1.19 ¦
6  ¦ Label 2 ¦ 1  ¦ 3.74 ¦
7  ¦ Label 3 ¦ 2  ¦ 4.52 ¦
8  ¦ Label 4 ¦ 3  ¦ 2.81 ¦
ect...

5. You can now *combine and "wrap" + new line* the columns together using functions in the field calculator

Open Field Calculator
Tick Create a new field
Output Field Name: Labels
Output field type: Text (string)
Output field length: 80

Expression:

"Name"  ||'/n' || "area"  || ' ha'

Name = attribute field with all the labels in it
Area = attribute field with all the areas

(You can use another wrap symbol instead of /n)

Then press OK

This creates

Attribute table be like this:

id ¦ Name    ¦ id2 ¦ area ¦ Labels  ¦
5  ¦ Label 1 ¦ 0   ¦ 1.19 ¦ Label 1 ¦
                          ¦ 1.19 ha ¦
6  ¦ Label 2 ¦ 1   ¦ 3.74 ¦ Label 2 ¦
   ¦         ¦     ¦      ¦ 3.74 ha ¦
7  ¦ Label 3 ¦ 2   ¦ 4.52 ¦ Label 3 ¦
   ¦         ¦     ¦      ¦ 4.52 ha ¦
8  ¦ Label 4 ¦ 3   ¦ 2.81 ¦ Label 4 ¦
   ¦         ¦     ¦      ¦ 2.81 ha ¦
ect...
(Can't seem to indent)

Press save as

Double click on the layer, or right click and go to properties, Labels
Select the drop down: show labels
Then select the new field called: Labels
Press Ok

The label + area should appear on the map

Then go to properties, Fields, select the id, Name, Id2 and area columns and delete these
Then save the layer

#### How to add labels to the polygon layer first

Create a new attribute, make that a string (text) and you can select each polygon in the attribute table, this makes the polygon go yellow (default colour) you then add the name to relevant column in the attribute table

#### You can export and possible reimport the data using MMQGIS

You could combine and adjust the attribute table in excel then join and reimport but field calculator is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Join Attributes by location should solve this.

Maybe you should save the edited layers first (Toogle off Editing).

Click to the pencil icon.

---

Try to intersect the two layers (that stores attributes from both layers):

**Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Intersection**

Input: Points

Intersect: Polygons

Comment: thanks, I am aware of the function, I have tried to clarify I need another step after this.

Comment: The problem could be that, you haven't saved the layers by finish editing.

Comment: I don't believe saving the layers is the issue.  The Join Attributes by location creates a new output shape file. I need to merge the 2 columns after the join attributes by location has been run.

Comment: I edited my answer, please try it, if it is possible.

Comment: thanks but I don't think your answer helps with the "wrapping" as discussed.
I have added some pictures, I think one needs to use excel to adjust the columns then reimport